# How to install Google Sketchup v8 on Wine?

Tags: wine

I am trying to install the last free version of Google SketchUp from before it became a webapp, on Wine.

The installer I have is `v8.0.16846`. When I open it with Wine 8.0.2, a dialog pops up with a progress bar (it doesn't say but I assume it's extracting files to a temp directory), the progress bar fills, and then the dialog disappears. Nothing else happens.

When I run it in a terminal, I see that the message `wineserver: file_set_error() can't map error: Function not implemented` is printed as it exits. There are no other messages that appear related.

How do I install this version of Google SketchUp on Wine?

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=41179

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a problem with Bottles, rather than Wine.

As a workaround, I tried to run `WINEPREFIX=/path/to/my/bottles/prefix wine /path/to/sketchup-setup.exe`. Twice, I got the message "Unable to find runtime to run the program" but it installed nonetheless.

I was then able to see SketchUp in Bottles, as it gets autodetected. When I ran it with bottles, I got the same message twice about not finding a runtime, but it ran anyway.